# App-V processes in the server task manager

Tags: virtualization, xenapp, app-v

I work for a vendor company that provides services for metering application usage in datacenter environments. We were recently asked whether we support App-V metering.

I have a question about App-V applications and their representation in the client machine that runs it. If I have a client machine A that runs an App-V packaged application, say MS Word, how does that application appear in the host task manager of the client machine? Does it appear with the same process name as it would normally without App-V prepackaging? (e.g. word.exe would show up in task manager). If not, are there common command line utilities/APIs available on the client machine for accessing this information.

Apologies if this is obvious, I couldn't find many straight-forward answers online.

Best,

Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it would appear quite the same as a non-virtualized, native Word.
There are ways to spot it as virtualized.

First you could look at the image path. Where the winword.exe is loaded from. If it is virtualized it would run from under C:\ProgramData\App-V\ (default location at least).

You can also identify it as virtualized by App-V is to look at loaded libraries. If AppVEntSubsystem32.dll is loaded, then it is virtualized.

I'm sure this is not a complete answer, but I hope it helps.